# Google Plus Sign In Cookie Policy on localhost

Tags: javascript, google-plus

I'm putting together a webapp that uses google plus signin using [this guide](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/).

I am running the webapp on `localhost:8888`.

Using javascript like this, things work fine:

```
    gapi.signin.render(thisHandle.details.buttonId, {
        'callback': mySignIn,
        'clientid': myClientId,
        'requestvisibleactions': 'http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity',
        'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login',
        'theme': 'light',
        'cookiepolicy': 'single_host_origin',
        'accesstype': 'offline'
    });
```

If I change my cookiepolicy to 'http:// localhost:8888' I get:

> Error: invalid_request Authority not strictly under a public suffix:
>   `localhost`:8888
>
> Request Details
>
> response_type=code token
>   id_token gsession scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login
>   redirect_uri=postmessage access_type=offline
>   cookie_policy=http://`localhost`:8888 proxy=oauth2relay874392806
>   origin=http://`localhost`:8888 state=384885884|0.12629541
>   client_id=[My client id]
>   request_visible_actions=http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity
>   authuser=0

What does **Authority not strictly under a public suffix** means in this context, in terms of storing user and session information? Is there a workaround that would allow me to have is running my development server? Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For your development work, you can stick with `single_host_origin` or use `none` (less efficient). The cookie policy is more important when your signed in user might be visiting your site on multiple protocols (http & https) or with subdomains (www.example.com and support.example.com). In those cases, you'd likely want to use the cookiepolicy of `http://example.com`