# gapi.auth2 returns 400 error when a domain is set for the cookie_policy

Tags: google-oauth, google-signin

Implemented `https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference` for my Angular app and logging in/out works fine.

---

However, when I set a domain for the `cookie_policy` parameter (tried `localhost` and a `.com` domain), after selecting my account, it returns a `400` error in the console. The URL for the error is the following:

`https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/iframerpc?action=issueToken&response_type=token%20id_token&scope=openid%20profile%20email&client_id=...apps.googleusercontent.com&login_hint=AJDL...r5Pg&ss_domain=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost&origin=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000`

The specific error message is:

```
{
  "error" : "invalid_request",
  "error_description" : "invalid login_hint."
}
```

This is blocking me for implementing authentication via gapi.auth2 that is shared across sub-domains.

Thanks!

Comment: Well it says right there you have an invalid login hint, so probably sort that out first, and then according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19886489/google-plus-sign-in-cookie-policy-on-localhost) you should be able to use single-host-origin or none for development or a url of your top level domain which should then also work for subdomains

Answer (score -1):

The values for cookie_policy are `single_host_origin` (the default) or `none`. I don't think you can set it to anything else.

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#gapiauth2initwzxhzdk20paramswzxhzdk21

Comment: But according to the [docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#gapiauth2authorizeparams-callback), `The domains for which to create sign-in cookies. Either a URI, single_host_origin, or none. Defaults to single_host_origin if unspecified.`